# How to prove this property of Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given a convex and twice differentiable function $f$, and
$\nabla f$ is Lipschitz with constant $L$, how to prove that
$(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \leq L \|x-y\|_2^2$ for all $x,y$

I just stuck at $|f(x)-f(y)||x-y| \leq L\|x-y\|^2_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have

\begin{align}
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^T(x-y) & \leq \left\| \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\right\|\left\|x-y \right\| \\
&\leq L\left\| x-y\right\|\left\| x-y\right\| \\
&=L \left\| x-y\right\|^2
\end{align}

where the second inequality is due to $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am not understanding your second part, because according to the definition of Lipschitz, shouldn't the inequality be $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \leq L\|x-y\|$?

Comment: If function $g$ is Lipschitz, then we have $$\left\|g(x)-g(y) \right\| \leq L \left\| x-y \right\|$$. Now, we have $g = \nabla f$.